# I need to create a query that selects the 5 states that have the most distinct customer IDs from a Defined Schema table I have made

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

How do I count distinct customer ids by state, and rank the states that have the most customer ids? I've listed the table creation code, and the schema code I was trying. Where am I going wrong?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS salesrecords_7
(
`Row ID` string,
`Order ID` string,
`Order Date` string,
`Ship Date` string,
`Ship Mode` string,
`Customer ID` string,
`Customer Name` string,
`Segment` string,
`Country` string,
`City` string,
`State` string,
`Postal Code` string,
`Region` string,
`Product ID` string,
`Category` string,
`Sub-Category` string,
`Product Name` string,
`Sales` string,
`Quantity` string,
`Discount` string,
`Profit` string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/g4240datastructures/data/salesrecords';
```

```
SELECT *, COUNT(customer id) AS log_count
FROM salesrecords_7
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY log_count DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: What mysql version? Add sample data and desired result. Also include the result you're getting with the current query and tell us what is the issue with it.

Comment: are all the id values distinct? or are there repeating id values, since they are customer_id im assuming its going ot repeat

Comment: oka so ur issue is the * you cant group by values and then select * attributes cause it doesn't know which to pick.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the '*', when you group by you can't access all the attributes of all the rows of the table cause they get grouped together.u also didn't have the distinct so you'd get repeating customer id values in ur count as well.

```
Select count(DISTINCT(customer id)) as log_count, state from salesrecords_7 
group by state
order by log_count DESC limit 5;
```

suggestion: try to avoid spaces in the database.